# How to cut a string from string and show last 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

A list of objects, what I need is that if I leave the chain of tasks too long, it breaks the table, or it looks aesthetically ugly, then I want to cut the chains and show the last 3 tasks, here in the image it shows me several tasks, what it returns is

data:[{tasks:"task 1 task 2 task 3 task 4}] and all the tasks can be added, so I want to cut and show the last 3. In such a way that my table does not break.

```
<tr
          v-for="item in presupuestos"
          :key="item.id"
          :style="item.id === presupuestoSeleccionado.id && TheStyle"
        >
          <td>{{ item.tipoPresupuestoString }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.numero }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.cliente.nombre }}</td>
          <td>{{ formatDate(item.fechaEntrega) }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.presupuestoComentarioString }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.tareas }}</td>
        </tr>

getList() {
  const tipoPresupuesto =
    this.tipoPresupuesto != null ? this.tipoPresupuesto : "";
  const clienteId = this.cliente != null ? this.cliente.id : "";
  const procesoId = this.proceso != null ? this.proceso : "";
  const tareaId = this.tareaFiltro != null ? this.tareaFiltro : "";

  Swal.fire({
    title: "Espere unos momentos ...",
    showConfirmButton: false,
  });
  this.presupuestoServices
    .getListSupervisar(tipoPresupuesto, clienteId, procesoId, tareaId)
    .then((data) => {
      Swal.close();
      this.presupuestos = data;
      console.log(data)
      this.$data.TheStyle.backgroundColor = "#c3bbbb"; //Para seleccionar los row de algun color
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      Swal.close();
      this.showError(error.response.data);
    });
},

[HttpGet("getListSupervisar")]public async  
   Task<ActionResult<List<Presupuesto>>>
    GetListSupervisar([FromQuery] 
                                                           int? tipoPresupuesto, [FromQuery] int? clienteId, 
                                                     
                                [FromQuery] int? 
                         procesoId, [FromQuery] int? tareaId)
{
string[] _include = { nameof(Presupuesto.Usuario), 
    nameof(Presupuesto.Cliente), 
    nameof(Presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle) + "." + 
    nameof(PresupuestoDetalle.PresupuestoDetalleProceso),
    nameof(Presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle) + "." + 
    nameof(PresupuestoDetalle.ArticuloBp),
    nameof(Presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle) + "." + 
    nameof(PresupuestoDetalle.ArticuloCamara),
    nameof(Presupuesto.PresupuestoTarea),
    nameof(Presupuesto.PresupuestoComentario)
};
var result = await _presupuestoServices.GetListAsync(a => a.Id > 0
                                                    && a.TipoPresupuesto!=null
                                                    && ((tipoPresupuesto == null && a.TipoPresupuesto != (int)Enumeraciones.PresupuestoTipo.Presupuesto) || a.TipoPresupuesto == tipoPresupuesto)
                                                    && (tareaId == null || a.PresupuestoTarea.Where(b => b.TareaId == tareaId).Count() > 0)
                                                    && (procesoId == null || a.PresupuestoDetalle.Where(b => b.PresupuestoDetalleProceso.Where(c => c.ProcesoId == procesoId && c.Cantidad < b.Cantidad).Count() > 0).Count() > 0)
                                                    && (clienteId == null || a.ClienteId == clienteId)
                                                    && a.PresupuestoDetalle.Count > 0
                                                    , _include);

var list = new List<Presupuesto>();

foreach (var presupuesto in result.ToList())
{
    //presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle = presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle.Where(a => a.EsPrimerCristal == true).ToList();
    presupuesto.Procesos = ArmarProcesosFaltantes(presupuesto);
    presupuesto.PresupuestoComentarioString = presupuesto.PresupuestoComentario.Count>0 ? presupuesto.PresupuestoComentario.LastOrDefault().Comentario : "";

    if (presupuesto.ImporteEnvio>0) 
    {
        presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle.Add(new PresupuestoDetalle() { Descripcion = "Envio", Cantidad = 1, Ancho = 1, Alto = 1,Presupuesto = presupuesto });
    }
    if (presupuesto.ImporteDescuento > 0) 
    {
        var descuentoPorcen = (presupuesto.DescuentoExtraPorcen + presupuesto.Cliente.Descuento)/100;
        presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle.Add(new PresupuestoDetalle() { Descripcion = "Descuento", Cantidad = 1, Ancho = descuentoPorcen, Alto = descuentoPorcen, Presupuesto = presupuesto });
    }
    if (presupuesto.ImporteColocacion > 0)
    {
        presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle.Add(new PresupuestoDetalle() { Descripcion = "Colocacion", Cantidad = 1, Ancho = 1, Alto = 1, Presupuesto = presupuesto });
    }

}

return result;
 }


ENTITIES DE PRESUPUESTO
public string Tareas
{
get
{
    var result = "";
    foreach (var item in PresupuestoTarea.OrderBy(a=>a.FechaAlta))
    {
        result = item.Descripcion + " " + result;
    }
    return result;
}
 }
 [NotMapped]
```

Comment: can you share a demo list of objects as code, its confusive by list of objects. do you mean js objects or just string. And also give an example what you want to extract from that list

Comment: There I could answer you, inadvertently I answered as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I am just adding my answer as per the problem statement you mentioned in first 2 paragraphs as looking into a whole code is like a trap.

You can achieve that with the help of `computed` property. You can slice all the remaining elements from an array and leave only last 3 elements.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    originalObject: [{
      id: 1,
      tipoPresupuestoString: 'tipoPresupuestoString 1',
      numero: 'Numero 1',
      fechaEntrega: 'fechaEntrega 1',
      presupuestoComentarioString: 'presupuestoComentarioString 1',
      tareas: 'tareas 1',
      cliente: {
        nombre: 'nombre 1'
      }
    }, {
      id: 2,
      tipoPresupuestoString: 'tipoPresupuestoString 2',
      numero: 'Numero 2',
      fechaEntrega: 'fechaEntrega 2',
      presupuestoComentarioString: 'presupuestoComentarioString 2',
      tareas: 'tareas 2',
      cliente: {
        nombre: 'nombre 2'
      }
    }, {
      id: 3,
      tipoPresupuestoString: 'tipoPresupuestoString 3',
      numero: 'Numero 3',
      fechaEntrega: 'fechaEntrega 3',
      presupuestoComentarioString: 'presupuestoComentarioString 3',
      tareas: 'tareas 3',
      cliente: {
        nombre: 'nombre 3'
      }
    }, {
      id: 4,
      tipoPresupuestoString: 'tipoPresupuestoString 4',
      numero: 'Numero 4',
      fechaEntrega: 'fechaEntrega 4',
      presupuestoComentarioString: 'presupuestoComentarioString 4',
      tareas: 'tareas 4',
      cliente: {
        nombre: 'nombre 4'
      }
    }, {
      id: 5,
      tipoPresupuestoString: 'tipoPresupuestoString 5',
      numero: 'Numero 5',
      fechaEntrega: 'fechaEntrega 5',
      presupuestoComentarioString: 'presupuestoComentarioString 5',
      tareas: 'tareas 5',
      cliente: {
        nombre: 'nombre 5'
      }
    }]
  },
  computed:{
    presupuestos() {
      return this.originalObject ? this.originalObject.slice(-3) : this.originalObject
    }
  }
})
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr
        v-for="item in presupuestos"
        :key="item.id"
        >
      <td>{{ item.tipoPresupuestoString }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.numero }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.cliente.nombre }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.fechaEntrega }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.presupuestoComentarioString }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.tareas }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```